# html5 video wont play on iPad - plays on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, html5-video

I have a m4v video that is able to play using html5 video tag on the iPhone - but it wont play on the iPad using html5. If i go directly to the video file from the iPad it plays fine- But if I use the html5 video tag to link to it the play button wont show. Im testing using an iPad 1 and iPhone 4 - both running iOS 5. Does anyone have an idea why it wont play on the iPad?

[Html5 video page](http://is.dk/test.html) - [Video URL](http://is.dk/video23.m4v)

Comment: Have you added the different mime-types to your web.config file? /Jan

Comment: It has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188269/html5-video-not-displaying-on-ipad

Answer (score 0):

Hey this probably won't help much for your situation but i found that with video streaming through a webview, it won't let you play video's past a certain file size.